# Virtual Private Server Using Multiple IP's

Tags: c#, proxy, ip, vps

Many Virtual Private Server(vps) providers give the option of having multiple dedicated IP's.

Can these IP's be used liked proxies from an application running on the VPS?

for instance, in C#, could I set the HttpWebRequest proxy property to use a specific dedicated IP for sending traffic? Would there have to be any other configuration to get that working?